# Eslint allow multiple parsers based on glob patterns

Tags: babeljs, eslint, typescript-eslint

My eslint parser as for now is `@typescript-eslint/parser`. I want to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` plugin, which requires `babel-eslint` parser.

I saw the `eslint-multiple-parsers` but it says that it was deprecated : 
**Use ESLint configuration based on glob patterns (`overrides`). See https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns**.

How can I set multiple parses that way?

Comment: Same issue here with `@angular-eslint/template-parser` and `@html-eslint/parser`. 

The only workaround i can think of is to run two commands with two different eslint config files. But sadly i can see no solution to get both kind of parsers into my code-editor.

Answer (score 17):

From the [Configuration Based on Glob Patterns](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns)

> A glob specific configuration works almost the same as any other ESLint config. Override blocks can contain any configuration options that are valid in a regular config, with the exception of root and ignorePatterns.

In your eslint config file you can add an `overrides` section which is an array of objects. Each object is required to have `files` key where you define the glob pattern. Any file which match will then use the overriden config. Example:

```
{
    // estree parser
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:security/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "security"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [ "error", 4 ]
    },
    // rest of your "normal" configuration here

    "overrides": [{
        // for files matching this pattern
        "files": ["*.ts"],
        // following config will override "normal" config
        "parser": "babel-eslint",
        "parserOptions": {
            // override parser options
        },
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
        ],
        "rules": [
            // override rules
        ],
    },
    }]
}
```

However if you already use `@typescript-eslint/parser` then you probably already match *.ts files, and overriding would only make every *.ts file use `babel-eslint` instead, which doesn't solve your issue.

I assume you want both parsers (typescript-eslint and babel) to run against same file, but I don't know easy solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

### Is your goal to run parser A against files X and parser B against files Y?

[@enterthenamehere-bohemian’s anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60672088/1537751) is the solution.

### Is your goal to run both parsers against the same files?

It depends…

###### Is your eslint running inside your editor?

As of today, I can see no solution inside a single eslint config file. You would need a single config file if you want to run it inside your editor.

###### Is your eslint running in your commandline or Continuous Integration environment?

You need three config files.

File `.eslintrc.json`

```json
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": ["./eslint-common-rules.json"],
    "rules": {
        …typescript parser rules here
    }
    …
}
```

File `.eslintrc.babel.json`

```json
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": ["./eslint-common-rules.json"],
    "rules": {
        …babel parser rules here
    }
    …
}
```

File `eslint-rules.json`

```json
{
    "rules": { … 
        …common eslint rules here
    }
    …
}
```

Having that, you can run both in your comanndline:

```sh
eslint # <- runs .eslintrc.json
eslint --config .eslintrc.babel.json
```