# Use ESLint plugin only for some files/directories

Tags: javascript, jestjs, eslint

I'm using the [ESLint plugin for Jest](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest) to lint my Jest tests. The structure of my project is

```
my-project
|
|--tests
   |
   |--unit
   |
   |--e2e
```

I only want to use the Jest plugin when linting files in the `tests/unit` dir (because the files in `tests/e2e` are not Jest tests), but when I run the linting, this plugin is applied to all files under `tests/unit`, which results in spurious errors in the `tests/e2e` files.

I can disable individual rules in the `tests/e2e` dir by adding the following to `eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    'jest/globals': true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  plugins: ['jest'],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["tests/e2e/*.js"],
      "rules": {
        "jest/no-disabled-tests": "off",
        "jest/expect-expect": "off",
        "jest/valid-expect-in-promise": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But rather than disabling individual rules in the `tests/e2e` dir, I would like to disable the Jest plugin completely.

Comment: How are you running eslint initially, git hook, CLI, editor plugin?

Answer (score 16):

From the [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work) regarding overrides:

> A glob specific configuration works almost the same as any other ESLint config. Override blocks can contain any configuration options that are valid in a regular config, with the exception of root and ignorePatterns.

Credit to the SO answer that helped me: [Eslint allow multiple parsers based on glob patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727078/eslint-allow-multiple-parsers-based-on-glob-patterns)

The example in that answer also demonstrates overriding plugins.

My example uses two overrides sections, one for JavaScript files and one for TypeScript. This could easily be two different directories.

```
{
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": "**/*.ts",
    "plugins": [
      "prettier",
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "eslint-config-prettier",
      "prettier",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "plugin:import/errors",
      "plugin:import/warnings",
      "plugin:import/typescript",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "rules": {
     
    }
  },
  {
    // Disabling TypeScript lint rules for JS files.
    "files": "**/*.js",
    "plugins": [
      "prettier"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "esnext",
      "eslint-config-prettier",
      "prettier",
      "plugin:import/errors",
      "plugin:import/warnings",
      "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "babel-eslint", 
    "parserOptions": {
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "rules": {
      
    }
  }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue and haven't found a built in solution in `eslint`'s config files, but you can try something that worked for me: ignore the E2E tests pattern in the main `eslintrc.js` and create another `eslintrc.js` file nested in the E2E directory.

as follows:

```
my-project
|-- eslintrc.js // this is your main eslint config
|--tests
   |
   |--unit
   |
   |--e2e
      |
      |-- eslintrc.js // nested eslintrc without the "jest" plugin
```

Note that you would have to tell the babel-eslint parser in the nested `eslintrc` where the babel config files is (usually as part of the `parserOptions`) since it is no longer in the same directory.

Main `eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    'jest/globals': true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
  ],
  parser: 'babel-eslint'
  plugins: ['jest'],
  ignorePatterns: ["tests/e2e/*.js"]
}
```

Nested `eslintrc.js` file in `tests/e2e/`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    babelOptions: {
      configFile: '../../babel.config.js' // assuming this is the name of your babel config file in the project root
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ignorePatterns` in your config file or create a `.eslintignore` file.

See: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories

Comment: This would completely disable eslint for those files, which is not what the OP is asking for.  He would like to only disable the Jest plugin for those files

Comment: They can specify the directory `tests/e2e` to exclude tests there, which is what they're asking for.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something... According to the docs, `ignorePatterns` looks to completely disable eslint running at all for those files. I think the OP still wants eslint to run on those files, just not including the jest plugin.

Comment: My understanding is that when they say ,"But rather than disabling individual rules in the tests/e2e dir, I would like to disable the Jest plugin completely", they are referring to the Jest Eslint plugin.